# downloading images of two different d3 graphs in single html page?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, html5-canvas

I created an html page for my tool which works offline(client side). This page is creating two different d3 based graph and I created two different buttons (save and save1)for each graph to downlaod images of these. These two image download button works fine, when tested separately in two different html pages.

Now, **Problem** in combined html page, is that each button is downloading the image of first d3 based graph only.

I defined two different svg variable (svg and svg1) for each graph creation but i donot know how to call it differently in downloadimage script.

**I think there is problem while calling "node( ).parentNode.innerHTML;" (mentioned in following svg downlaod script)?
But I don't know how to call different SVG in this script.
This is my first time, I am working on d3.
**

```
d3.select("#save1").on("click", function(){  //button save in first graph;
  var html1 = d3.select("svg")           //var html in first graph;
    .attr("version", 1.1)
    .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
    .node( ).parentNode.innerHTML;   
    //console.log(html);

  var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(html1);
  var image = new Image;
    image.src = imgsrc;

image.onload = function() {
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = image.width;
canvas.height = image.height;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
context.fillRect(0,0,image.width,image.height);
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = "image.png";
a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
document.body.appendChild(a);
 a.click();
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
 var html1 = d3.select("svg")
```

Is always selecting the first SVG in the DOM, regardless the button you click.

Instead of that, give your SVGs unique IDs (like `svg1` and `svg2`), and select by those IDs:

```
 var html1 = d3.select("#svg1")

 var html2 = d3.select("#svg2")
```

Comment: I defined two separate divisions <div id="heatmap"> </div>   and <div id="ballgraph"></div> for each graph. and I called this as you told "var html = d3.select("#heatmap")" and "var html1 = d3.select("#ballgraph")' . but in this case button is not working at all.

Comment: This is how i defined my graph                                                                  "var svg = d3.select('#heatmap').append("svg"); and                                     "var svg1 = d3.select('#ballgraph').append("svg").

Comment: Set the IDs to the SVGs, not to the divs. Like this: `var svg = d3.select('#heatmap').append("svg").attr("id", "svg1")`... the same for the second SVG (with a different ID, of course).

Comment: I tried this also but didn't work. here are the combinations :                           var svg = d3.select('#heatmap').append("svg").attr("id","svg1") and              var svg1 = d3.select('#ballgraph').append("svg").attr("id", "svg2")  and                                                               svg divisions like   <div id="heatmap"><svg id="svg1"></svg> ,    <div id="ballgraph"><svg id="svg2"></svg>     and in image download script var html1 = d3.select("#svg1")
Is there any other suggestions? or mistakes. I tried with svg class also but not working.
 var html2 = d3.select("#svg2")

Comment: Yes, Button id is different in both cases.

Comment: At this point, I can't help you unless you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). However, the problem with your was already addressed. Look at this fiddle, you can see that my solution works: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/nLwavn17/

Comment: yes it worked after removing <svg id="svg1"></svg> from                       "<div id="heatmap"><svg id="svg1"></svg></div" and var svg = d3.select('#heatmap').append("svg").attr("id", "svg1")  and .....